# $_SERVER is not updating when switching from webpage

Tags: php, nginx, ipb

I'm trying to get the current url I'm in with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.
I'm using IPS Community software and there is what is called a "block". The code is inside this block and this block is added on my website's template (so when I'm navigating the block is always there).

The first time I'm making the request (first page visited) the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is good. But if I'm going on another one the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is not updated. It has the first value and not a new one.

After few tests I've come to the conclusion that I've to wait for like a minute to request a new value.

Is it normal ? Does it come from IPS ? Does it come from nginx ? Is there another way to know my current url ? Can I force the value to be updated ?

Comment: Given that this is a core PHP variable, I don't think anyone's going to believe you without code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: My code is quite simple :
    {expression="$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']"}

Comment: The answer will depend a lot on how the server was set up. I don't think we can answer this

Comment: So this can come from the nginx configuration ?

Comment: @naurel It doesn't come from the configuration. NGINX is just passing on information about the current HTTP request when it runs the script.

Comment: Does this also affect other variables like `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`?

Comment: It's the whole $_SERVER variable that isn't updated

Comment: This sounds like it may be some sort of issue specific to IPB. Have you tried asking their support team?